# Saving a video to the library - Error -3302 "there was a problem writing this asset..."

Tags: ios

I'm trying to save a video/image after recording/taking a picture and I'm getting "There was a problem writing this asset because the data is invalid and cannot be viewed or played".

Error code is -3302. The thing is that I'm not really doing anything with the data before attempting to save it.
Here's the code I run:

Code:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
{      
    NSURL* mediaURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    if(mediaURL)
    {   //The user has recorded a video and it's kept on a temporary directory
       if(UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum([mediaURL path]))
       {
           //Save the video to user library
           UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum([mediaURL path], self,               @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:context:), nil);                                        

           //Remove it from the temporary directory it was saved at
           [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[mediaURL path] error:nil];
       }
   }
}
```

And that's it. Do I need to do something to the data before attempting to save it?

Thanks.